# AWS EB deploy doesn't work due to no enabled repos

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My backend server is developed on Ruby on Rails. It runs on Amazon linux in AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

I always use eb deploy to deploy the server to AWS EB, but it suddenly doesn't work.

There is a `.ebextensiions` folder in the project folder. One of configuration file `postgis_install.config` has below configuration command:

```
  01-install-testabc-repo:
    command: sudo yum-config-manager --add-repo https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/testabc-repo/testabc-repo.repo

  02-refresh-yum-cache:
    command: sudo yum makecache

  03-install-geos:
    command: sudo yum --disablerepo="*" --enablerepo="testabc-repo*" install -y geos geos-devel
    test: if rpm -q geos geos-devel &>/dev/null; then exit 1; else exit 0; fi
```

The error log when I deploy the server is given as below:

Error logs:

```
  Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
  adding repo from: https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/testabc-repo/testabc-repo.repo
  grabbing file https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/testabc-repo/testabc-repo.repo to /etc/testabc.repos.d/testabc-repo.repo
  Could not fetch/save url https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/testabc-repo/testabc-repo.repo to file /etc/yum.repos.d/testabc-repo.repo: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 403 - Forbidden
  
[2021-06-02T04:22:30.552Z] INFO  [2651]  - [Application deployment app-95f7-210519_032224@1/StartupStage0/EbExtensionPreBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild/prebuild_2_testabc/Command 02-refresh-yum-cache] : Starting activity...
[2021-06-02T04:22:33.991Z] INFO  [2651]  - [Application deployment app-95f7-210519_032224@1/StartupStage0/EbExtensionPreBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild/prebuild_2_testabc/Command 02-refresh-yum-cache] : Completed activity. Result:
  Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
  Metadata Cache Created
  
[2021-06-02T04:22:33.991Z] INFO  [2651]  - [Application deployment app-95f7-210519_032224@1/StartupStage0/EbExtensionPreBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild/prebuild_2_testabc/Test for Command 03-install-geos] : Starting activity...
[2021-06-02T04:22:34.015Z] INFO  [2651]  - [Application deployment app-95f7-210519_032224@1/StartupStage0/EbExtensionPreBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild/prebuild_2_testabc/Test for Command 03-install-geos] : Completed activity. Result:
  
  Completed successfully.
[2021-06-02T04:22:34.016Z] INFO  [2651]  - [Application deployment app-95f7-210519_032224@1/StartupStage0/EbExtensionPreBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild/prebuild_2_testabc/Command 03-install-geos] : Starting activity...
[2021-06-02T04:22:34.157Z] INFO  [2651]  - [Application deployment app-95f7-210519_032224@1/StartupStage0/EbExtensionPreBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild/prebuild_2_testabc/Command 03-install-geos] : Activity execution failed, because: Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
  There are no enabled repos.
  Run "yum repolist all" to see the repos you have.
  You can enable repos with yum-config-manager --enable <repo>
   (ElasticBeanstalk::ExternalInvocationError)
```

It seems the issue is caused by the failure of fetch the repo from S3 bucket. Could you please give me any hints for solving this problem?

Comment: Did you add S3 permissions to your EB instance role?

Comment: Yes. I have added S3 permissions, but doesn't work.